# Generic Helm Chart - Troubles with the application name

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have many services that I will need to deploy to Kubernetes.  While the values vary, the installation structure is the same for 85% of them.  I would like to use a generic helm chart for that 85%.

At first this looked to be very doable, I can just pass in a custom `values.yaml` file for each chart.

But then I realized that the contents of chart.yaml cannot be overridden.  Specifically, the `appVersion` and `name` properties need to be overridden for each deploy.

Do I really need to maintain a separate chart for all these cookie cutter microservices?  **Or is there a way to make a generic chart and override the `appVersion` and `name` properties in the chart.yaml file?**

Answer (score 0):

I did a bit more digging and found that this was requested in 2018.

https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/3555

It go no movement (but a lot of votes).  Eventually it got closed as stale.  It was re-requested here:

https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/8194

It has some good strong arguments in support of it, but no movement from the helm team.

Looks like the consensus (as far a workaround as) is to download the chart, unpack it, modify the helm chart programmatically, then deploy it.  It will work, but it is cumbersome and unwieldy...

Answer (score 0):

You probably do need to "create a chart" with a separate `Chart.yaml` file for each service, but you can move the actual implementation out to a shared library chart.

Write a normal Helm chart that has the 85%-common parts.  You can test deploying it if you'd like, but it will probably take most of the interesting parts as values.  Make sure this is accessible somewhere; the two easiest options will be in a chart repository or as part of a monorepo.

Now your service chart just needs to include to include the shared chart.  Using Helm 3 syntax, this could look like:

```yaml
apiVersion: 2           # Helm 3 syntax with inline requirements
name: some-service
version: 0.0.1
appVersion: 20210317
dependencies:
  - name: application   # the shared chart
    version: '^1.0'
    repository: 'http://helm.example.com/charts'
```

In the service chart's `values.yaml` file, you need to make sure to include to shared-chart settings under a key matching the `name:` (or, if the shared chart is so configured, `global:`):

```yaml
application:
  redis:
    enabled: false
```

If you're depending on the settings in the `Chart.yaml` file, the shared-library chart will see its own `Chart.yaml` as `.Chart`, which can affect generated names (if you name things `{{ .Release.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Name }}-suffix` they will see the library's `.Chart.Name`, not the service's).

The service chart doesn't actually need its own `templates`, and I believe the chart will install correctly if the `templates` directory isn't there.  You can add more YAML in `templates` if you need to.  The harder part is suppressing or modifying what's in the library chart, and mostly that will need to support every possible option a service might need.  (You can wrap an entire YAML file in `{{ if }}...{{ end }}`, or include multiple YAML objects in the same file separated by `---`, which can both help provide this kind of option.)