# Does helm include a way to unpackage a chart?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

If I have a folder called `my-helm-chart` that has my helm chart, I can run:

```
helm package my-helm-chart
```

and it will create a file called `my-helm-chart-1.0.0.tgz`.

I am wondering if helm has a command to undo this?  (I need to [modify the chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66662379/generic-helm-chart-troubles-with-the-application-name) before deploying.)

Comment: I think you can directly untar your chart.tar.gz file

Answer (score 8):

Use **"helm pull"**
to download a chart from a repository and **(optionally) unpack** it in local directory
https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_pull/

For example:

```
helm pull "bitnami/redis" --untar
```

Answer (score 3):

It's a standard tar archive.

`tar xf my-helm-chart-1.0.0.tgz` to un-tar it and then package it again when you've finished modifying it.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of doing this you can add your repo to your helm with

```
helm add repo xxxx yyyyy
```

Then when you edit your chart just use

```
helm push . xxxx
```

from the chart directory.

This is how I do it because last minute changes are a thing :)
Good day.